# Why use metal cake pan instead of silicone one?

Tags: baking, cake, pan

I've been using silicone cake pans in my electric oven for a while and they work great and cakes come out easily and washing then is also very convenient. However I see that there're lots of traditional metal cake pans of the same form in shops and so I guess they are in demand.

Why use a metal cake pan and not a silicone one?

Comment: As you said in your question: traditional pans are traditional. That's one big reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't it have to do with insulation?  A heavy, well insulated cake pan results in less doming of the cake.  If you're baking a layer cake you want minimal doming which mean less trimming to get everything even.  Also, I believe you're supposed to get a more uniform texture since the rise is more even.

Comment: Plus, silicone is harder to clean, and it makes me nervous because it's floppy.  I'm always afraid I'll drop something.

Answer (score 7):

Dark metal pans provide superior browning for breads, muffins, and the like that are better with a crust on them. In my personal experience, foods do NOT release well and they are NOT convenient to clean. I actually have thrown out my silicone muffin and loaf "pans" because of their abysmal results. I've never baked a cake in silicone, though.